# Can I pass an array instead of multiple related arguments to the function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a function which provides a HTML for me. Something like this:

```
function user_profile ($name, $age, $location){
    return "<div class='myclass' style='color:red'>
                <span class='title'>user's profile</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Name: $name</li>
                    <li>Age: $age</li>
                    <li>location: $location</li>
                </ul>
            </div>";
} 

echo user_profile ($name, $age, $location);
```

Function above is a simplified of my real function. In reality, that function has 14 arguments and the HTML is much more longer.

Anyway, I want to know can I make it more clean? I mean, can I make an array of all arguments and just pass it *(the array)*? In that case how can I use it into the function?

Again, in reality my code is much bigger and the above one is just a sample.

Comment: you can pass an array or object as a parameter to your function which would make accessing each of the individual parameters much easier and more maintainable

Comment: Are all elements will go under the **<ul>** tag ?

Comment: @developer Not really, in reality there is some dynamic variables which are wrapped into other tags.

Comment: You can leave the function as is and use `call_user_func_array()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can pass an array as an argument. In your code it would look something like this:

```
function user_profile ($array){
    return "<div class='myclass' style='color:red'>
                <span class='title'>user's profile</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Name: $array[0]</li>
                    <li>Age: $array[1]</li>
                    <li>location: $array[2]</li>
                </ul>
            </div>";
} 

//variables in the following array are defined elsewhere in script - not revelant here

$array = array($name, $age, $location);
echo user_profile($array);
```

A more attractive way to do this would be to use key-value pairs via an associative array:

```
function user_profile ($array){
    return "<div class='myclass' style='color:red'>
                <span class='title'>user's profile</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Name: " . $array['Name'] . "</li>
                    <li>Age: " . $array['Age'] . "</li>
                    <li>location: " . $array['Location'] . "</li>
                </ul>
            </div>";
} 

//variables in the following array are defined elsewhere in script - not revelant here

$array = array('Name' => $name, 'Age' => $age, 'Location' => $location);
echo user_profile($array);
```

This method, using associative arrays, would allow you to more easily match array keys with the HTML list item content.

Comment: The OP wanted to make it "more clean". So the question is if these numbered array[0], array[1]... make it cleaner than those original named parameters. I don't think so.

Comment: @Al Kepp, OP wanted to know how to pass an array - it's in the title of the post. Clean or not is definitely based on the opinion of each user

Comment: @AlKepp Is right .. maybe it would be better if you define some names for each key of that array separately. thank you anyway .. upote

Comment: Was just writing an answer using array with keys but you fixed it so upvote and also this should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Passing array as an argument is the only clean way to do as [The One and Only ChemistryBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2687790/the-one-and-only-chemistryblob) said. But can be improved by let it be more dynamic as array can be passed with any number of information.

```
function user_profile ($array){
    $return ="<div class='myclass' style='color:red'>
                <span class='title'>user's profile</span>
                <ul>".PHP_EOL;
    foreach($array as $key=> $value){
         $return .="<li>".$key.": ".$value."</li>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    $return.="</ul>
            </div>";
    return $return;
} 

$try =['Name' => $name, 
      'Age' => $age, 
      'Location' => $location];

echo user_profile($try);
```